# How to programmatically authenticate users to OpenAM in Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, authentication, tomcat7, openam

Trying to migrate our web application from GlassFish2 (GF) to Tomcat7 (TC).

In GF we used AuthContext approach (like in [this example](http://docs.forgerock.org/en/openam/11.0.0/dev-guide/#chap-authentication)) to login users using PolicyAgent3 (PA), after which we received UserPrincipal with roles in next Requests.

In TC the same approach didn't work yet. I can login the user, but I don't get UserPrincipal in next Requests. I managed to make PA's sampleapp work, but it uses Form Authentication (through OpenAM), which doesn't suit us.

Is it possible to use AuthContext approach in TC at all? Because comparing agent.jar implementations in GF and TC, I came to the conclusion that it might not be supported. In GF's PA there is implementation of IJ2EEAuthenticationHandler (com.sun.identity.agents.appserver.v81.AmASJ2EEAuthHandler) that authenticates user and sets UserPrincipal in the process, but in TC's PA there is only default implementation of handler (com.sun.identity.agents.filter.J2EEAuthenticationHandler), which doesn't set UserPrincipal, its authenticate method just returns true.

Is AuthContext approach supported in Tomcat or not? How else is it possible to programmatically authenticate users to OpenAM and get UserPrincipals?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by AuthContext approach? Do you refer to the ClientSDK's authentication API, or is AuthContext some container-specific authentication mechanism?

Comment: I refer to OpenAM Java SDK's authentication API, like in [this example](http://docs.forgerock.org/en/openam/11.0.0/dev-guide/#chap-authentication)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Authenticating using the AuthContext API on its own will not populate the Java EE declarative roles. In order to get those populated you will have to log into the Java EE realm, which should be possible several ways:

- perform a form based login (configure web.xml accordingly and then modify the agent profile settings, so it becomes aware of the login and error endpoints).
- not something I've tested but I would assume that HttpServletRequest#login should work as well.
- use the container's means of performing programmatic authentication.

What you need to be aware of is that the Java EE agents do not log in the user based on username/password, instead, there is a complex String structure (called transport string in the code base), which contains the user's SSOTokenID, that will be used to determine the user's name and roles.

Also keep in mind that containers tend to implement declarative security differently. In the past I've found that Tomcat requires quite a few web.xml additions in order to enable declarative security with the agents. For me the bare minimum to get declarative security to work was:

```
<security-constraint>
 <web-resource-collection>
  <web-resource-name>matchall</web-resource-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </web-resource-collection>
 <auth-constraint>
  <role-name>AUTHENTICATED_USERS</role-name>
 </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just want to add that I needed to perform a form based login, as you said. Something, that wasn't used on GF. It is described in details [by Oracle here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19681-01/820-4803/auto17/index.html).
Security constraint was also needed, this also wasn't required on GF. After you login user using AuthContext you need to move to some protected page and only then PA will set userPrincipal.
And when you use AuthContext you need to add SSOToken's ID as a value to cookie iPlanetDirectoryPro. It could have a different name, see com.iplanet.am.cookie.name.